# Create Pdf Documents using IText#

Tags: c#, itext

How can I create a pdf document with tables, which looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Add Namespace:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

code using c#:

```
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFirstPDF.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);


    doc.Open();


    var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/ABsIS_Logo.jpg"));
    logo.SetAbsolutePosition(430, 770);
    logo.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(30);
    logo.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(70);
    doc.Add(logo);

    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
    table1.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
    table1.WidthPercentage = 80;

    var titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 24);
    var subTitleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 16);

    PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell();
    cell11.Colspan = 1;
    cell11.AddElement(new Paragraph("ABC Traders Receipt", titleFont));

    cell11.AddElement(new Paragraph("Thankyou for shoping at ABC traders,your order details are below", subTitleFont));


    cell11.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

    PdfPCell cell12 = new PdfPCell();


    cell12.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


    table1.AddCell(cell11);

    table1.AddCell(cell12);


    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3);

    //One row added

    PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell();

    cell21.AddElement(new Paragraph("Photo Type"));

    PdfPCell cell22 = new PdfPCell();

    cell22.AddElement(new Paragraph("No. of Copies"));

    PdfPCell cell23 = new PdfPCell();

    cell23.AddElement(new Paragraph("Amount"));


    table2.AddCell(cell21);

    table2.AddCell(cell22);

    table2.AddCell(cell23);


    //New Row Added

    PdfPCell cell31 = new PdfPCell();

    cell31.AddElement(new Paragraph("Safe"));

    cell31.FixedHeight = 300.0f;

    PdfPCell cell32 = new PdfPCell();

    cell32.AddElement(new Paragraph("2"));

    cell32.FixedHeight = 300.0f;

    PdfPCell cell33 = new PdfPCell();

    cell33.AddElement(new Paragraph("20.00 * " + "2" + " = " + (20 * Convert.ToInt32("2")) + ".00"));

    cell33.FixedHeight = 300.0f;



    table2.AddCell(cell31);

    table2.AddCell(cell32);

    table2.AddCell(cell33);


    PdfPCell cell2A = new PdfPCell(table2);

    cell2A.Colspan = 2;

    table1.AddCell(cell2A);

    PdfPCell cell41 = new PdfPCell();

    cell41.AddElement(new Paragraph("Name : " + "ABC"));

    cell41.AddElement(new Paragraph("Advance : " + "advance"));

    cell41.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

    PdfPCell cell42 = new PdfPCell();

    cell42.AddElement(new Paragraph("Customer ID : " + "011"));

    cell42.AddElement(new Paragraph("Balance : " + "3993"));

    cell42.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;


    table1.AddCell(cell41);

    table1.AddCell(cell42);


    doc.Add(table1);

    doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have look also at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Category/20, some handy samples of stuff people are often after it

PS: AbhiRoczz... personally I do avoid roseindia as they tend to steal plenty of resources, meaning they will copy&paste without giving credit to original owner. Plus site is badly organized and have one to many adverts

Comment: roseindia is actually a very bad site, with lot of bad practices and flaws

Comment: @VishalAnand yeap, and nothing changed since I posted above. It went even worse

Answer (score 1):

Check out following examples of using Itext.

[Itext Examples for tables lists and images](http://www.roseindia.net/java/itext/index.shtml)

You can further search for html to pdf converter. There are lot of free tools available. You need to pass your html containing the table and it will return the pdf document. I have developed one such application. Let me know if u need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
          byte[] bPDF = null;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Document document = new Document(); //pdf document to write
   var originalpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/PDFs/");
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(originalpath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(originalpath);
                // Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the outputstream

                var pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

                // Open the Document for writing
                document.Open();
                PdfPTable ParentTable = new PdfPTable(1);
                 ParentTable.TotalWidth = 500f;
                             ParentTable.LockedWidth = true;
                ParentTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                ParentTable.ExtendLastRow = false;
                PdfPCell heading = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", HeaderFont));
                heading.PaddingBottom = 0f;
                heading.PaddingTop = 0f;
                heading.Border = 1;
                ParentTable.AddCell(heading);
                PdfPTable dataTableCellHeaderTable = new PdfPTable(3);
                dataTableCellHeaderTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                float[] widths = new float[] { 2f, 2f, 5f };
                dataTableCellHeaderTable.SetWidths(widths);
              PdfPCell cellSerialNumber = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ScoringColoringModel.pdfFirstCellHeading, tableHeaderCellFont)) { Border = 0 };
                cellSerialNumber.PaddingTop = 7.5f;
                cellSerialNumber.PaddingBottom = 7.5f;
                cellSerialNumber.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
                cellSerialNumber.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D3D3D3").ToArgb());
                dataTableCellHeaderTable.AddCell(cellSerialNumber);


                PdfPCell cellRegistration = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ScoringColoringModel.pdfSecondCellHeading, tableHeaderCellFont)) { Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER };
                cellRegistration.PaddingTop = 7.5f;
                cellRegistration.PaddingBottom = 7.5f;
                cellRegistration.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
                cellRegistration.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D3D3D3").ToArgb());
                dataTableCellHeaderTable.AddCell(cellRegistration);

                PdfPCell cellwordMark = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ScoringColoringModel.pdfThirdCellHeading, tableHeaderCellFont)) { Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER };
                cellwordMark.PaddingTop = 7.5f;
                cellwordMark.PaddingBottom = 7.5f;
                cellwordMark.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D3D3D3").ToArgb());
                cellwordMark.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
                dataTableCellHeaderTable.AddCell(cellwordMark);
                // to append more data create one table
                PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(3);

                Font cellColor = new Font();

                foreach (DataRow dr in objDataTable.Rows)
                {

                    if (dr.ItemArray[5].ToString() == "Yellow")
                    {

                        cellColor = FontFactory.GetFont(ScoringColoringModel.pdfFontSet, 12, new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffa800").ToArgb())); ;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cellColor = FontFactory.GetFont(ScoringColoringModel.pdfFontSet, 12, new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(dr.ItemArray[5].ToString()).ToArgb())); ;
                    }

                    dataTableCellHeaderTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(), cellColor)) { PaddingBottom = 5, Border = 1, PaddingTop = 5 });



         dataTableCellHeaderTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dr.ItemArray[1].ToString(), cellColor)) { PaddingBottom = 5, Border = 1, PaddingTop = 5 });

                        dataTableCellHeaderTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dr.ItemArray[3].ToString(), cellColor)) { PaddingBottom = 5, Border = 1, PaddingTop = 5 });

                    }
    //Here you can add multiple table 





                  document.Add(ParentTable);
    //document.Add(ParentTable1); and add table one by one to the document 

                    document.Close();
                    bPDF = ms.ToArray();
                    // Close the writer instance

                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TrademarkSearchResult.pdf");
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bPDF);
                    Response.End();
                }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

***Create PDF Letter Using Itext Sharp***

```
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font fontRupee = new Font(bf, 8, Font.ITALIC);
    Font fontRupee1 = new Font(bf, 10, Font.BOLDITALIC);


    var Smallspace = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 1, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var boldHeadFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 13, iTextSharp.text.Color.RED);
    var boldTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 11, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontSmall = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);

    var TableFontmini_ARBold8Sub = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBoldCom = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 16, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBoldComAdd = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10, Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBold82 = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 7, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBold81 = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 7, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_Ver = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_VerBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBoldWef8 = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 9, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBold8 = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8.5f, Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    //var TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 7, Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBold8inc = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8.5f, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var TableFontmini_ARBoldRef = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 9, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, 10);
    var boldFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, 8, Font.UNDERLINE);
    var boldFontm = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC, 9);
    //var boldFontm = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD | iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE);
    //var boldFontm= FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE);
    var TableFontmini_Ar = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
    iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    iTextSharp.text.Font timessmall = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);


    var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12);
    var boldFonts = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);

    var blackListTextFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 28, Color.BLACK);
    var redListTextFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 28, Color.RED);






    rnPL.Id = Id.SelectedValue.Trim();
    rnPL.Code = Code;
    rnPL.CodeNo = CodeNo;

    DataSet ds = rnBL.GetDetilForPDF(rnPL);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["tbl_Basic"];
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
       // lblHidId.Value = dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();

        if (dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString() == "4")
        {
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("images") + "\\1.jpg";
            FilePathstamplogo = Server.MapPath("images") + "\\6.png";
        }



        if (dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("images") + "\\2.jpg";
            FilePathslogo = Server.MapPath("images") + "\\5.png";
        }






            //iTextSharp.text.Image stamplogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(FilePathstamplogo);
            //stamplogo.ScalePercent(75f);

            ////stamplogo.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.PageSize.Width - 36f - 140f, doc.PageSize.Height - 36f - 640f);/*ByAbhishek*/
            //stamplogo.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.PageSize.Width - 38f - 160f, doc.PageSize.Height - 38f - 700f);
            //doc.Add(stamplogo);




        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(FilePath);
        jpg.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(830);
        jpg.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(600);
        jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
        fofile = "";
        fofile = Server.MapPath("PDFComRNew");
        string crefilename;
        crefilename = Convert.ToInt32(Code.ToString()).ToString() + Convert.ToInt32(CodeNo.ToString()).ToString() + ".Pdf";
        string newPathfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(fofile, crefilename);
        PdfWriter pdfwrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(newPathfile, FileMode.Create));

        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(jpg);

        PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);
        tableHeader.WidthPercentage = 50;
        PdfPCell Headspace;

        Headspace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontSmall));
        Headspace.BorderWidth = 0;
        Headspace.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
        tableHeader.AddCell(Headspace);

        Headspace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontSmall));
        Headspace.BorderWidth = 0;
        Headspace.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
        tableHeader.AddCell(Headspace);



        Headspace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontSmall));
        Headspace.BorderWidth = 0;
        Headspace.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
        tableHeader.AddCell(Headspace);
        doc.Add(tableHeader);
        #endregion



        PdfPTable tblAcNo = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthsaccingo = { 1000 };
        tblAcNo.SetWidths(colWidthsaccingo);
        PdfPCell celladdingo;

        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);
        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);
        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);
        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);
        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);
        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);
        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);

        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);

        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);


        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);

        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);

        celladdingo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontmini_ARBold8));
        celladdingo.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        celladdingo.BorderWidth = 0;
        celladdingo.Colspan = 1;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(celladdingo);

        //Chunk c111 = new Chunk("Ref No : ", TableFontmini_ARBoldRef);
        //Chunk c211 = new Chunk((dt.Rows[0]["RefrenceNo"]).ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor);
        //Phrase p211 = new Phrase();
        //p211.Add(c111);
        //p211.Add(c211);
        Paragraph pS = new Paragraph();
        //pS.Add(p211);
        /*For gst*/
        /*For space*/
        Chunk cspc = new Chunk("                                                                                                    ", TableFontmini_ARBold8);
        Phrase pcspc = new Phrase();
        pcspc.Add(cspc);
        pS.Add(pcspc);
        /*For space*/

        /*For statecode*/
        Chunk c1111 = new Chunk("Date : ", TableFontmini_ARBoldRef);
        Chunk c2111 = new Chunk((dt.Rows[0]["GenearteDate"]).ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor);
        Phrase p2111 = new Phrase();
        p2111.Add(c1111);
        p2111.Add(c2111);

        pS.Add(p2111);
        /*For statecode*/

        /*For finally add*/
        PdfPCell cellDet_4 = new PdfPCell(pS);
        cellDet_4.HorizontalAlignment = 0; /**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
        cellDet_4.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellDet_4.Colspan = 2;
        tblAcNo.AddCell(cellDet_4);

        doc.Add(tblAcNo);



        PdfPTable tblto = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthTo = { 1000 };
        tblto.SetWidths(colWidthTo);
        PdfPCell cellTo;

        cellTo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellTo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellTo.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellTo.Colspan = 2;
        tblto.AddCell(cellTo);

        cellTo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellTo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellTo.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellTo.Colspan = 2;
        tblto.AddCell(cellTo);

        cellTo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellTo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellTo.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellTo.Colspan = 2;
        tblto.AddCell(cellTo);

        cellTo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellTo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellTo.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellTo.Colspan = 2;
        tblto.AddCell(cellTo);

        cellTo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellTo.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellTo.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellTo.Colspan = 2;
        tblto.AddCell(cellTo);

        cellTo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("To, ", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellTo.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cellTo.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellTo.Colspan = 1;
        tblto.AddCell(cellTo);

        doc.Add(tblto);



        PdfPTable tblToManager = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthToManager = { 1000 };
        tblToManager.SetWidths(colWidthToManager);
        PdfPCell cellToManager;

        cellToManager = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellToManager.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellToManager.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellToManager.Colspan = 2;
        tblToManager.AddCell(cellToManager);

        cellToManager = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellToManager.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cellToManager.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellToManager.Colspan = 1;
        tblToManager.AddCell(cellToManager);
        doc.Add(tblToManager);

        PdfPTable tblBillHead = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthBillHead = { 1000 };
        tblBillHead.SetWidths(colWidthBillHead);

        PdfPCell celltblBillHead = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(dt.Rows[0]["Header"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8));
        celltblBillHead.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        celltblBillHead.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblBillHead.Colspan = 1;
        tblBillHead.AddCell(celltblBillHead);

        doc.Add(tblBillHead);

        PdfPTable tblSiteAdd = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthSiteAdd = { 1000 };
        tblSiteAdd.SetWidths(colWidthSiteAdd);

        PdfPCell celltblSiteAdd = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        celltblSiteAdd.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        celltblSiteAdd.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblSiteAdd.Colspan = 1;
        tblSiteAdd.AddCell(celltblSiteAdd);

        doc.Add(tblSiteAdd);

        PdfPTable tblSiteCity = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthSiteCity = { 1000 };
        tblSiteCity.SetWidths(colWidthSiteCity);

        PdfPCell celltblSiteCity = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(dt.Rows[0]["City"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8));
        celltblSiteCity.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        celltblSiteCity.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblSiteCity.Colspan = 1;
        tblSiteCity.AddCell(celltblSiteCity);
        doc.Add(tblSiteCity);



        PdfPTable tblSubject = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthSubject = { 1000 };
        tblSubject.SetWidths(colWidthSubject);
        PdfPCell cellSubject;

        cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
        tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

        cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
        tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);


        cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
        tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

        cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
        tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

        cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("   Sub.: Application For leave", TableFontmini_ARBold8Sub));
        cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
        cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellSubject.Colspan = 1;
        tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

        doc.Add(tblSubject);



        PdfPTable tblDEarSir = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthDEarSir = { 1000 };
        tblDEarSir.SetWidths(colWidthDEarSir);
        PdfPCell cellDEarSir;

        cellDEarSir = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellDEarSir.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellDEarSir.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellDEarSir.Colspan = 2;
        tblDEarSir.AddCell(cellDEarSir);

        cellDEarSir = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellDEarSir.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellDEarSir.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellDEarSir.Colspan = 2;
        tblDEarSir.AddCell(cellDEarSir);

        cellDEarSir = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellDEarSir.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellDEarSir.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellDEarSir.Colspan = 2;
        tblDEarSir.AddCell(cellDEarSir);

        cellDEarSir = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dear Sir, ", TableFontmini_ARBold8));
        cellDEarSir.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cellDEarSir.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellDEarSir.Colspan = 1;
        tblDEarSir.AddCell(cellDEarSir);
        doc.Add(tblDEarSir);

        PdfPTable tblPara1 = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthPara1 = { 1200 };
        tblPara1.SetWidths(colWidthPara1);
        PdfPCell cellPara1;

        cellPara1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellPara1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellPara1.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara1.Colspan = 4;
        tblPara1.AddCell(cellPara1);

        cellPara1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellPara1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellPara1.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara1.Colspan = 4;
        tblPara1.AddCell(cellPara1);

        cellPara1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellPara1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellPara1.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara1.Colspan = 4;
        tblPara1.AddCell(cellPara1);

        cellPara1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("i beg to say that i m feelling unwell", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellPara1.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        cellPara1.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara1.Colspan = 1;
        tblPara1.AddCell(cellPara1);
        doc.Add(tblPara1);

        PdfPTable tblPara2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthPara2 = { 1400 };
        tblPara2.SetWidths(colWidthPara2);
        PdfPCell cellPara2;

        cellPara2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellPara2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellPara2.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara2.Colspan = 4;
        tblPara2.AddCell(cellPara2);
        cellPara2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellPara2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellPara2.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara2.Colspan = 4;
        tblPara2.AddCell(cellPara2);

        cellPara2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Kindly give me leave for four days ", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellPara2.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        cellPara2.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara2.Colspan = 1;

        tblPara2.AddCell(cellPara2);

        doc.Add(tblPara2);

        PdfPTable tblPara3 = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthPara3 = { 1200 };
        tblPara3.SetWidths(colWidthPara3);
        PdfPCell cellPara3;
        cellPara3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellPara3.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellPara3.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara3.Colspan = 4;
        tblPara3.AddCell(cellPara3);

        cellPara3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(" from Date" + dt.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellPara3.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        cellPara3.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellPara3.Colspan = 1;
        tblPara3.AddCell(cellPara3);
        doc.Add(tblPara3);

        PdfPTable tblLastPara = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthLastPara = { 1200 };
        tblPara1.SetWidths(colWidthLastPara);
        PdfPCell cellLastPara;

        cellLastPara = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellLastPara.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellLastPara.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellLastPara.Colspan = 2;
        tblLastPara.AddCell(cellLastPara);

        cellLastPara = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellLastPara.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellLastPara.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellLastPara.Colspan = 2;
        tblLastPara.AddCell(cellLastPara);

        cellLastPara = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellLastPara.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellLastPara.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellLastPara.Colspan = 2;
        tblLastPara.AddCell(cellLastPara);

        cellLastPara = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Thank you so much for giving me leave", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellLastPara.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        cellLastPara.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellLastPara.Colspan = 1;
        tblLastPara.AddCell(cellLastPara);
        doc.Add(tblLastPara);

        PdfPTable tblThankingYou = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthThankingYou = { 1000 };
        tblSiteCity.SetWidths(colWidthSiteCity);
        PdfPCell celltblThankingYou;

        celltblThankingYou = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celltblThankingYou.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celltblThankingYou.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblThankingYou.Colspan = 2;
        tblThankingYou.AddCell(celltblThankingYou);

        celltblThankingYou = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celltblThankingYou.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celltblThankingYou.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblThankingYou.Colspan = 2;
        tblThankingYou.AddCell(celltblThankingYou);

        celltblThankingYou = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        celltblThankingYou.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        celltblThankingYou.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblThankingYou.Colspan = 2;
        tblThankingYou.AddCell(celltblThankingYou);

        celltblThankingYou = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Thanking You,", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        celltblThankingYou.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        celltblThankingYou.BorderWidth = 0;
        celltblThankingYou.Colspan = 1;
        tblThankingYou.AddCell(celltblThankingYou);
        doc.Add(tblThankingYou);

        PdfPTable tblYorsSinc = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthYorsSinc = { 1000 };
        tblYorsSinc.SetWidths(colWidthYorsSinc);
        PdfPCell cellYorsSinc;

        cellYorsSinc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellYorsSinc.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellYorsSinc.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellYorsSinc.Colspan = 2;
        tblYorsSinc.AddCell(cellYorsSinc);

        cellYorsSinc = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Sincerely Yours,", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
        cellYorsSinc.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cellYorsSinc.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellYorsSinc.Colspan = 1;
        tblYorsSinc.AddCell(cellYorsSinc);
        doc.Add(tblYorsSinc);

        PdfPTable tblAuthSignat = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthAuthSignat = { 1000 };
        tblAuthSignat.SetWidths(colWidthAuthSignat);
        PdfPCell cellAuthSignat;

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);
        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 2;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);

        cellAuthSignat = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("(Student Signatature)", TableFontmini_ARBold8));
        cellAuthSignat.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellAuthSignat.Colspan = 1;
        tblAuthSignat.AddCell(cellAuthSignat);
        doc.Add(tblAuthSignat);

        PdfPTable tblForCom = new PdfPTable(1);
        float[] colWidthForCom = { 1000 };
        tblYorsSinc.SetWidths(colWidthForCom);
        PdfPCell cellForCom;

        cellForCom = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
        cellForCom.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cellForCom.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellForCom.Colspan = 2;
        tblForCom.AddCell(cellForCom);

        cellForCom = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("For  " + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8));
        cellForCom.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cellForCom.BorderWidth = 0;
        cellForCom.Colspan = 1;
        tblForCom.AddCell(cellForCom);
        doc.Add(tblForCom);



            pdfwrite.PageEvent = new FooterRN(dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(Code.ToString()).ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Studentmail"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["PhoneNo1"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["StudentName"].ToString());


        doc.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void FormPage(string Code)
    {
        #region For Set Pdf FontSize,FontStyle FontColor etc..!!
        #region for rs font
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font fontRupee = new Font(bf, 8, Font.ITALIC);
        Font fontRupee1 = new Font(bf, 10, Font.BOLDITALIC);
        #endregion

        #region My Project
        var Smallspace = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var boldHeadFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 13, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED);
        var boldTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 11, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontSmall = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);


        var TableFontmini_ARBold82 = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 7, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBold81 = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 7, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_Ver = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_VerBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBold10 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

        var TableFontmini_GorBold12 = FontFactory.GetFont("Georgia", 12, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBold12 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBold11 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBold8inc = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8.5f, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var TableFontmini_ARBoldRef = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 9, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, 10);
        var boldFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, 9, Font.BOLD);
        var boldFontm = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC, 9);

        var boldFontTax = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC, 9, Font.UNDERLINE);

        var TableFontmini_Ar = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        iTextSharp.text.Font timessmall = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        #endregion

        #region server

        //var Smallspace = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 1, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var boldHeadFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 13, iTextSharp.text.Color.RED);
        //var boldTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 11, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontSmall = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);


        //var TableFontmini_ARBold82 = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 7, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBold81 = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 7, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_Ver = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_VerBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBold10 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBold12 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBold11 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBold8inc = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8.5f, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var TableFontmini_ARBoldRef = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 9, Font.BOLDITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, 10);
        //var boldFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, 9, Font.BOLD);
        //var boldFontm = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC, 9);

        //var boldFontTax = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC, 9, Font.UNDERLINE);

        //var TableFontmini_Ar = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        //iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        //iTextSharp.text.Font timessmall = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        #endregion

        #endregion


        #region For Get All Records..!!


        CPL.EmpCode = Code;
        CPL.ForFormEleven = "1";
         DataTable dt = CBL.GetEmpDetailForPDF(CPL);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
                       
            iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f);
            #region For PDF File And PDF Folder..!!
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("Billinglatestimages") + "\\Cash.jpg";
            #endregion
            #region For PDF File And PDF Folder..!!
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(FilePath);
            jpg.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(1600);
            jpg.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(900);
            jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;

            #region New Writing region
            string dbfileName = null;/*This varialble is Used for storing the filenames in database.*/
            string DocPath = null;/*This varialble is Used for Craetting  the File path .*/
            DocPath = Server.MapPath("~/HRD/EmpFormEleven/") + "/";
            //DocPath = Server.MapPath("~/HRD/SiteWiseHRLetter/") + HidSiteCode.Value + "/" + hidLetterId.Value + "/";
            if (!(Directory.Exists(DocPath)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DocPath);
            }
            fofile1 = "";
            fofile1 = DocPath;
            string crefilename1;
            crefilename1 = Convert.ToInt32(InvoiceNo.ToString()).ToString() +"_1" +".Pdf";
            string newPathfile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(fofile1, crefilename1);
            PdfWriter pdfwrite1 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(newPathfile1, FileMode.Create));
            #endregion
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(jpg);
            #endregion

            #region PDF Header Section Start..!!
            PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);
            tableHeader.WidthPercentage = 100;
            PdfPCell Headspace;
          
            Headspace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontSmall));
            Headspace.BorderWidth = 0;
            Headspace.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            tableHeader.AddCell(Headspace);

            Headspace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", TableFontSmall));
            Headspace.BorderWidth = 0;
            Headspace.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            tableHeader.AddCell(Headspace);
            doc.Add(tableHeader);
            #endregion

            #region For Header 1
            PdfPTable tblSubject = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthSubject = { 1600 };
            tblSubject.SetWidths(colWidthSubject);
            PdfPCell cellSubject;

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);
            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            cellSubject = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellSubject.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellSubject.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject.Colspan = 2;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject);

            PdfPCell cellSubject1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("FORM No-11 (New) Declaration Form", TableFontmini_ARBold11));

            cellSubject1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellSubject1.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellSubject1.Colspan = 1;
            tblSubject.AddCell(cellSubject1);
            doc.Add(tblSubject);
            #endregion

            #region For Header2
            PdfPTable tblHeader2 = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthHeader2 = { 1600 };
            tblHeader2.SetWidths(colWidthHeader2);
            PdfPCell cellHeader2;

            cellHeader2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader2.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader2.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader2.AddCell(cellHeader2);



            cellHeader2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader2.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader2.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader2.AddCell(cellHeader2);

            PdfPCell cellHeaderL = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("(To be retained by the employer for future reference )", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));

            cellHeaderL.HorizontalAlignment = 1;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellHeaderL.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeaderL.Colspan = 1;
            tblHeader2.AddCell(cellHeaderL);
            doc.Add(tblHeader2);
            #endregion

            #region For Header3
            PdfPTable tblHeader3 = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthHeader3 = { 1600 };
            tblHeader3.SetWidths(colWidthHeader3);
            PdfPCell cellHeader3;

            cellHeader3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader3.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader3.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader3.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader3.AddCell(cellHeader3);


            PdfPCell cellHeader3L = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("EMPLOYEES' PROVIDENT FUNDS ORGANISATION", TableFontmini_GorBold12));
            cellHeader3L.HorizontalAlignment = 1;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellHeader3L.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader3L.Colspan = 1;
            tblHeader3.AddCell(cellHeader3L);
            doc.Add(tblHeader3);
            #endregion

            #region For Header4
            PdfPTable tblHeader4 = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthHeader4 = { 1600 };
            tblHeader4.SetWidths(colWidthHeader4);
            PdfPCell cellHeader4;

            cellHeader4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader4.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader4.AddCell(cellHeader4);

            PdfPCell cellHeader4L = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Employee's Provident Funds Scheme,1952 (Paragraph 34 & 57 ) & Employee's  Pension Scheme, 1995(Paragraph 24)", TableFontmini_ARBold10));
            cellHeader4L.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellHeader4L.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader4L.Colspan = 20;
            tblHeader4.AddCell(cellHeader4L);
            doc.Add(tblHeader4);
            #endregion

            #region For Header5
            PdfPTable tblHeader5 = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthHeader5 = { 1600 };
            tblHeader5.SetWidths(colWidthHeader5);
            PdfPCell cellHeader5;

            cellHeader5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader5.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader5.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader5.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader5.AddCell(cellHeader5);

            PdfPCell cellHeader5L = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Declaration by a person taking up employment in an establishment on which Employee's Provident Fund Scheme, 1952 and / or Employee's Pension Scheme, 1995 is applicable.", TableFontmini_ARBold10));
            cellHeader5L.HorizontalAlignment = 0;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellHeader5L.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader5L.Colspan = 20;
            tblHeader5.AddCell(cellHeader5L);
            doc.Add(tblHeader5);
            #endregion

            #region For Header6
            PdfPTable tblHeader6 = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthHeader6 = { 1600 };
            tblHeader6.SetWidths(colWidthHeader6);
            PdfPCell cellHeader6;

            cellHeader6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader6.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader6.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader6.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(cellHeader6);


            PdfPCell cellHeader6L = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("(PLEASE GO THROUGH THE INSTRUCTIONS)", TableFontmini_ARBold11));
            cellHeader6L.HorizontalAlignment = 1;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellHeader6L.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader6L.Colspan = 1;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(cellHeader6L);
            doc.Add(tblHeader6);
            #endregion

            #region For Line Space
            PdfPTable tblHeader7 = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] colWidthHeader7 = { 1600 };
            tblHeader7.SetWidths(colWidthHeader7);
            PdfPCell cellHeader7;

            cellHeader7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            cellHeader7.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellHeader7.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader7.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader7.AddCell(cellHeader7);


            PdfPCell cellHeader7L = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("  ", TableFontmini_ARBold11));
            cellHeader7L.HorizontalAlignment = 1;/**Left=0,Centre=1,Right=2**/
            cellHeader7L.BorderWidth = 0;
            cellHeader7L.Colspan = 1;
            tblHeader7.AddCell(cellHeader7L);
            doc.Add(tblHeader7);
            #endregion


            #region Name..!!

            PdfPTable tblName = new PdfPTable(3);
            float[] colWidthsaccing4 = { 100, 500, 700};
            tblName.SetWidths(colWidthsaccing4);
            PdfPCell celladdingo4;
            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1.", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            
            celladdingo4.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblName.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  Name :", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            celladdingo4.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblName.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" " +dt.Rows[0]["EmpName"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            celladdingo4.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblName.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);


            doc.Add(tblName);

            #endregion

            #region DOB..!!

            PdfPTable tblDOB = new PdfPTable(3);
            float[] colWidthsaccingDOB = { 100, 500, 700 };
            tblDOB.SetWidths(colWidthsaccingDOB);
            PdfPCell cellDOB;
         

            cellDOB = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("2.", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellDOB.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            cellDOB.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellDOB.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblDOB.AddCell(cellDOB);

            cellDOB = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  Date Of Birth :(DD/Mm/YYYY)", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellDOB.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellDOB.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellDOB.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblDOB.AddCell(cellDOB);

            cellDOB = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" " + dt.Rows[0]["EmpDOB"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellDOB.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellDOB.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellDOB.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblDOB.AddCell(cellDOB);

           

            tblDOB.AddCell(cellDOB);
            doc.Add(tblDOB);

            #endregion

            #region tblFatherHusbandName..!!

            PdfPTable tblFatherHusbandName = new PdfPTable(3);
            float[] colWidthsaccingFatherHusbandName = { 100, 500, 700 };
            tblFatherHusbandName.SetWidths(colWidthsaccingFatherHusbandName);
            PdfPCell cellFatherHusbandName;


            cellFatherHusbandName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("3.", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellFatherHusbandName.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            cellFatherHusbandName.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellFatherHusbandName.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblFatherHusbandName.AddCell(cellFatherHusbandName);

            cellFatherHusbandName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  Father's / Husband Name :", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellFatherHusbandName.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellFatherHusbandName.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellFatherHusbandName.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblFatherHusbandName.AddCell(cellFatherHusbandName);

            cellFatherHusbandName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" " + dt.Rows[0]["FatherHusbandName"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellFatherHusbandName.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellFatherHusbandName.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellFatherHusbandName.BorderWidth = 0.5f;

            tblFatherHusbandName.AddCell(cellFatherHusbandName);
            doc.Add(tblFatherHusbandName);

            #endregion

            #region RelationShip..!!

            PdfPTable tblRelationShip = new PdfPTable(3);
            float[] colWidthRelationShip = { 100, 500, 700 };
            tblRelationShip.SetWidths(colWidthRelationShip);
            PdfPCell cellRelationShip;


            cellRelationShip = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("4.", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellRelationShip.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            cellRelationShip.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellRelationShip.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblRelationShip.AddCell(cellRelationShip);

            cellRelationShip = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  Relationship in Respect of (3) above :", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellRelationShip.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellRelationShip.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellRelationShip.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblRelationShip.AddCell(cellRelationShip);

            cellRelationShip = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" " + dt.Rows[0]["RelationShip"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellRelationShip.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellRelationShip.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellRelationShip.BorderWidth = 0.5f;

            tblRelationShip.AddCell(cellRelationShip);
            doc.Add(tblRelationShip);

            #endregion

            #region RelationShip..!!

            PdfPTable tblGender = new PdfPTable(3);
            float[] colWidthGender = { 100, 500, 700 };
            tblGender.SetWidths(colWidthGender);
            PdfPCell cellGender;


            cellGender = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("5.", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellGender.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            cellGender.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellGender.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblGender.AddCell(cellGender);

            cellGender = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  Gender :", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellGender.HorizontalAlignment = 0;

            cellGender.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellGender.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblGender.AddCell(cellGender);

            cellGender = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" " + dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            cellGender.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cellGender.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            cellGender.BorderWidth = 0.5f;

            tblGender.AddCell(cellGender);
            doc.Add(tblGender);

            #endregion

            /*HR Signature Add*/
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            string imageURL = Server.MapPath("~/HRD/Billinglatestimages/") + "EPFLogo.png";
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
            //Resize image depend upon your need
            jpg1.ScaleToFit(85f, 85f);
            //jpg1.SetAbsolutePosition(80, 380);
            jpg1.SetAbsolutePosition(60, 730);
            jpg1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Add(jpg1);
            /*HR Signature Add*/

            /*Emp Signature Add*/




            //Resize image depend upon your need

            /*HR Signature Add*/

            PdfContentByte content = pdfwrite1.DirectContent;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(doc.PageSize);
            rectangle.Left += doc.LeftMargin;
            rectangle.Right -= doc.RightMargin;
            rectangle.Top -= doc.TopMargin;
            rectangle.Bottom += doc.BottomMargin;
            rectangle.BorderWidthLeft = 0.5f;
            rectangle.BorderWidthRight = 0.5f;
            rectangle.BorderWidthTop = 0.5f;
            rectangle.BorderWidthBottom = 0.5f;
            content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
            content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
            content.Stroke();


            doc.Close();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: In your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52666643/1729265) from 2018 you at least added a header to a wall of code, here there's only such a wall...