# How Do I Convert a Asp.Net Panel to PDF using iTextSharp or Any Other Library?HTML Worker Depreciated

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm Trying to Print out a Receipt in my Web app project using itextsharp and i keep getting either no  response on clicking the button or a blank pdf when i try to convert it to xml.

1st function uses itextsharp and gives the error below
error says htmlworker depreciated 
2nd function uses itextsharp.xmlworker and tries to
convert to xml using XMLWorkerHelper
but i just get a blank pdf

here's the asp page

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="1141px" Width="1583px">
            <table class="auto-style4" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style6">Retail Invoice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style7">Order Id:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        Order Date:&nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style12">
                        <table border="1" class="auto-style8">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="auto-style9">Buyer Address:<br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="auto-style11">Seller Address:<br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="PharmaStore Inc."></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style12">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="266px" Width="1571px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="sno" HeaderText="Sr.No" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Product ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productname" HeaderText="Product Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="totalprice" HeaderText="Total Price" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style10">Grand Total:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style12">
                        <br />
                        Disclaimer:<br />
                        <br />
                        We Declare that this invoice shows the actual price of the goods descibed inlusive of taxes and that all particulars are true and correct.<br /> Incase you find the selling price on this invoice to be more than the MRP mentioned on the product,<br /> Please inform us at <a href="mailto:wrongmrp@pharmastore">wrongmrp@pharmastore.com</a><br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        THIS IS A COMPUTER GENERATED INVOICE AND DOES NOT REQUIRE A SIGNATURE .</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style5" Height="189px">
        </asp:Panel>
```

1st function gives the error below

```
private void exportpdf()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OrderInvoice.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            Panel1.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
#pragma warning disable CS0612 // Type or member is obsolete
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
#pragma warning restore CS0612 // Type or member is obsolete
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
```

2nd Function blank pdf

```
        protected void exportpdf()
        {
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    Panel2.RenderControl(hw);
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OrderInvoice.pdf");
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    //                 XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The document has no pages.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The document has no pages.

Source Error: 


Line 49: #pragma warning restore CS0612 // Type or member is obsolete
Line 50:             htmlparser.Parse(sr);
Line 51:             pdfDoc.Close();
Line 52:             Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Line 53:             Response.End();

PharmaStore\PlacedSuccessfully.aspx.cs    Line: 51 

Stack Trace: 


[IOException: The document has no pages.]
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree() +1042
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close() +285
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close() +318
   iTextSharp.text.Document.Close() +110
   PharmaStore.PlacedSuccessfully.exportpdf() in source\repos\Pharmastore\PharmaStore\PlacedSuccessfully.aspx.cs:51
   PharmaStore.PlacedSuccessfully.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in source\repos\Pharmastore\PharmaStore\PlacedSuccessfully.aspx.cs:32
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +31
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3466

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0
```

Comment: I will suggest you use iTextSharp
look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776090/create-pdf-documents-using-itext

Comment: Thank you for the help.I'll try it out.