# How to use itext 7 to generate a PDF from an HTML div and save it to a folder on the server in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm trying to create a CV builder that saves the CV edited by the user to a folder in my project for further processing of sending it through email, I have reached as far as using itext to create a PDF of an HTML div, but has no CSS or any of the text values I have returned from my database. Through some research i find that my problem could be solved by using itext 7 and an add-on pdfHTML but can not find any proper examples of how to use it with my ASP.NET code. Would really appreciate any help.

Bellow is the code for the on-click button event I use to generate the PDF

```
    protected void ButtonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    contentdiv.RenderControl(hw); //convert the div to PDF
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    string filename = base.Server.MapPath("~/PDF/" + "UserCV.pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs(filename, false);
    Response.End();
}
```

[This picture shows the pdf result i get when i click the download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLeF.png)
[And this is html page it is trying to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBSEi.png)
The text bellow the headings on the HTML page are Labels whose values are being set by retrieving values form a database

Comment: This will help you with creating PDFs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776090/create-pdf-documents-using-itext

Comment: @Bosco unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to use `pdfHTML`

This example is quite extensive, as it also sets document properties, and registers a custom Font.

```
public void createPdf(String src, String dest, String resources) throws IOException {
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

    WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
    //Add metadata
    writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();

    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
    //Set the document to be tagged
    pdfDoc.setTagged();
    pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));

    //Set meta tags
    PdfDocumentInfo pdfMetaData = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
    pdfMetaData.setAuthor("Joris Schellekens");
    pdfMetaData.addCreationDate();
    pdfMetaData.getProducer();
    pdfMetaData.setCreator("JS");
    pdfMetaData.setKeywords("example, accessibility");
    pdfMetaData.setSubject("PDF accessibility");
    //Title is derived from html

    // pdf conversion
    ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
    FontProvider fp = new FontProvider();
    fp.addStandardPdfFonts();
    fp.addDirectory(resources);//The noto-nashk font file (.ttf extension) is placed in the resources

    props.setFontProvider(fp);
    props.setBaseUri(resources);
    //Setup custom tagworker factory for better tagging of headers
    DefaultTagWorkerFactory tagWorkerFactory = new AccessibilityTagWorkerFactory();
    props.setTagWorkerFactory(tagWorkerFactory);

    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdfDoc, props);
    pdfDoc.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

The most relevant line here is

```
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdfDoc, props);
```

Which essentially tells `pdfHTML` to perform the conversion of the inputstream (specified by src), put the content in `pdfDoc` and use the given `ConverterProperties` (specified by `props`).

Comment: Joris Thank you for your answer. I was able to generate a pdf but it was not generating the values I retrieved  from my database, that I set as label values. So the whole pdf just has the words 'Labels' written all over it. Would appreciate further help on this issue

Comment: Let's start out easy. Update your code-snippet to what you are actually using now. I assume you are using pdfHTML now.
Also, if you are buying this product (or testing it with the intent to buy it) you can also request support from iText itself.

Comment: I have updated my question with pictures of the HTML page I am trying to convert to PDF and the resulting PDF I get when I run my code, looking at them I hope you get a better understanding of my problem. I was unable to use your code snippet as it refers to Java code of which I know very little about and no I have no intent of buying the product

Comment: And how are those values being set?
Because your code does not show this.
Javascript?

Comment: I'm using ASP Datasets to set the values of the labels after retrieving the data from the database(SQL Server 2016) and storing it in the Dataset `string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

                string querry1 = "select * from AspNetUsers where Id='" + User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString() + "' ";
                var adapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(querry1, connString);
                var comm1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt1);
                var ds1 = new DataSet();
                adapt1.Fill(ds1, "Users");`